# JSX syntax, tags were not supporting on React.js accidentally

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a **React.js** project with only .js documents using visual studio Code.For a long time it was successfuly being developed with including **JSX tags** inside javascript files.There were no errors or problems.But at once,when I use npm run start,it shows many JSX tag errors as unsupported,without changing the code.**I cleaned cache,Reinstalled node modules,Reinstalled VS code,Reinstalled NPM** .**Instead of VS code,I used Atom**.But problem could not be solved.On other laptops,this project works well and other projects with .js files with JSX syntaxes performs well on my device.I tried an earlier github folder of this same project,but it is also not working.Below problem was shown on terminal when I run,**npm run start**.(There are lot of files on project which leads to this error)

> **Syntax error: C:/software project/my-app/src/App.js: Unexpected token (108:3)**

Comment: Can you post your code here?

Comment: Have you tried to change the extension of `App.js` into `App.jsx`?

Comment: No i did not try it,because sometimes I experienced changing the extension leads a file missing problem. this is my repo https://github.com/ksandaru/voting_app.git

Comment: @JamesLin https://github.com/ksandaru/voting_app.git

Comment: @BenoitChassignol now i changed App.js to App.jsx , but nothing changed.error still exists.

Comment: The error is releated about React Fragment at the line 108 of your App.js.

Comment: @BenoitChassignol Yeah,i tested removing all <> and </> tags,When i removed them,it indicates more jsx tags with same issue.These all fragments worked well before yesterday.

Comment: You have recently bumped the version of `react-scripts` from `4.0.3` to `1.1.5`. Are you sure about that?

Comment: @BenoitChassignol I did not aware of that kind of thing.How can i solve that mismatch,please..

Comment: https://github.com/ksandaru/voting_app/blob/2d6ad15ff2007061f66e5116600c16a690259397/package.json#L31 undo this line. and run `npm install` and `npm run start`

Comment: @BenoitChassignol  Thank you very much.It is worked...I was fed up with this issue.You solved it.Thank you.I replaced that line with "react-scripts": "^4.0.3", and  run npm install,it worked.

Comment: @keysan no problem, it's a pleasure, I made a clean answer :)

Comment: @BenoitChassignol yeah.Great! :-)

Comment: @keysan you can mark my answer as accepted to resolve your topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resume:

The problem is that a dependency as been changed.

https://github.com/ksandaru/voting_app/blob/2d6ad15ff2007061f66e5116600c16a690259397/package.json#L31 undo this line. and run npm install and npm run start